# Проблема в отображение главной страницы WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с очень странной проблемой: установил `WordPress` на `LAMP`. Когда зашел после установки, то поначалу всё отображалось четко, как надо, но потом, когда начал ознакамливаться с меню и т.д. и т.п., почему-то сайт резко начал отображаться без `css`. Пытаюсь найти проблему, может кто-то с похожим сталкивался?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в кодере и человеческом факторе.

Comment: Во первых консоль в помощь. Во вторых ctl+z. Нужно делать анализ действий, отмену изменений и смотреть шо да как

Comment: Привет, да согласен с тобой так как я начинающий на LAMP, что то мог сделать не так, вообщем буду чекать, спс за совет

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163802/no-css-being-loaded-on-backend/309277

Comment: Смог решить проблему, просто больше искал на ру комьюнити, но решил зайти на англ и мне помогло. Я define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true ); вписал в wp-config.php и заменил error_reporting(0); на error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); в wp-admin/load-styles.php file,